# Rails 4 + Zurb Foundation 5 framework error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

trying to use the Zurb Foundation 5 framework w Rails 4.2.1 as stated in the tuts (http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/rails-and-foundation-part-1/ ) I get the following error ..

```
Invalid CSS after "...ules: $modules ": expected "}", was "!global;"
```

in my gem file I requested the gems :

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails' 
gem 'foundation-rails'
 ...
```

in my assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
```

in my assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
$(function(){$(document).foundation();});
```

it's my first try to use Foundation ( until then I was using Bootstrap..) it does not seems so easy as Bootstrap3 + RAilS.. or something is missing in the tuts...

Answer (score 1):

solved using the latest gem

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6148

and specifying

```
gem 'foundation-rails', '5.4.5'
```

in the Gemfile